# What is the entry point of Spark container in YARN cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

What is the main entry point of a Spark executor when a Spark job is being run in Yarn cluster mode (for Spark 1.2.0+)?

What I am looking for is the Scala class name for the entry point of an Executor (which will be the process executing one of the tasks on a slave machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking about is [org.apache.spark.executor.Executor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala) or perhaps [org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L187). It is `TaskRunner` that will ultimately [run a task](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L274-L277).

It is regardless of the deploy mode (`client` vs `cluster`) or the cluster manager used, i.e. Hadoop YARN or Spark Standalone or Apache Mesos.

Answer (score 2):

```
spark-submit --class [FULLY QUALIFIED CLASS NAME]
             --master yarn-cluster
             [JAR_TO_USE]
```

So, given the above, the class to be used is the one specified, which is loaded from the given jar, and it searches within that class for a `static main` method.

From [SparkSubmit.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ebff7327af5efa9f57c605284de4fae6b050ae0f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala):

```
val mainMethod = mainClass.getMethod("main", new Array[String](0).getClass)
```